# In jquery, get value of another cell in same row of gridview

Tags: jquery, gridview, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an image within a TemplateField in a GridView

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="start_dt">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="StDt" runat="server" CssClass="StartDate" Text='<%# Eval("start_dt", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="StDt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("start_dt", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="startdtimage" CssClass="StartDateImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/pencil.gif" Visible='<%# HasUpdateStartDateRole() %>' Width="18px" Height="18px" onclientclick="javascript:return false;"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
            </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:BoundField DataField="hire_dt" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
                HeaderText="Hire Date" ReadOnly="True" />
        </Columns>
```

I have a datepicker attached to the image.

```
$(".StartDateImg").datepicker({
                duration: '',
                showTime: false,
                constrainInput: false,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    alert($(this).parents().find(".hire_dt").html()); 
                    $(this).parents().find("span")[0].innerHTML = dateText; }

            });
```

Within this datepicker, I want to get the value of another cell in this row (from the hire_dt column).

***EDIT***
I was able to get it using
`$(this).parents().closest('tr').find('td:last').html()` since it's the last column in the row.  I'd prefer to use the "hire_dt" id though, in case the table is every altered in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse your markup with jquery.  Likely StartDateImg is, well, an image.  Then its parent is likely a TD, and its parent is likely the TR.

Your easiest path to a sibling TD (or at least a child of the same TR with a set class) is:  `$(this).closest('tr').find('.hire_dt')`

Comment: See edit above, was able to get it using `last`. Both of these return null `alert($(this).parents().closest('tr').find('.hire_dt').html());
                    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.hire_dt').html());`

Comment: You still didn't post the ***resulting*** HTML.  I want to see your output, not snippets of your ASP.NET.  But here's my guess: you're finding based on hire_dt class.  I don't see in your code where you assign anything to that class.  Using a Bound field on field "hire_dt" will not also give it that class name, so it can't find any elements with class hire_dt.